# App crashes on exit when using ListFragment called from a Sliding Tab's Fragment adapter

Tags: android-listview, android-fragments

I have spend almost two day trying to figure out why this is happening but couldn't find a solution so far. So I am posting it here.

I have a pretty generic Sliding Tab which is created in Eclipse for newer Android APIs. Inside one of the sliding tabs I call a ListFragment. This ListFragment uses CursorLoader to load some data.

Now when the app exits, it gives: 05-28 11:34:00.327: E/AndroidRuntime(31994): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to destroy activity {com.example.myapp/com.example.myapp.main.HomeActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException

I have tried using ChildFragmentManager and also the latest support package, but to no avail.

This is the only tab which calls another fragment, otherwise rest of the tabs which just call static XML content work just fine. App works fine if I remove this tab.

As I understand I need to destroy the CursorLoader or somehow detach this particular fragment before the app exits. CursorLoader seems to get destroyed, and the error is caught in HomeActivty. Maybe I should call onDestroy in HomeActivity, but really don't know how and where exactly.

Code of the calling HomeActivity is pretty standard:

```
ViewPager mViewPager;
private static final String DEBUG_TAG = "MY APP"; 

private static boolean logged_in;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

    sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    logged_in = sharedPrefs.getBoolean("logged_in", false);

    Log.v(DEBUG_TAG, "logged_in: " + logged_in);

    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.home, menu);
    return true;
}


public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        Fragment fragment;

        switch(position) {
        case 0:
              fragment = new MySectionFragment();
            break;
        case 1:
                ...
```

The code which calls the ListFragment from the FragmentActivity is as follows:

```
public static class MySectionFragment extends Fragment {
    public MySectionFragment() {}

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_my_section, container, false);
    }

    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView(); 
        Fragment fragment = (getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_my_section));

        if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.remove(fragment);
            ft.commitAllowingStateLoss();   
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the answer and it was in the most unexpected place in the code. I still don't understand the mechanics, but I have confirmed throughly that it works.

I am using Android 4.0.3 with support library rev 12.

Turned out that my code was perfectly fine and I didn't even need onDestroyView(). Views get destroyed and regenerated fine. There was no need to deal with FragmentManager, SupportFragmentManager or ChildSupportFragmentManager. The default code which is generated in Eclipse when selecting swipable tabs is just fine.

The only place where I made a change, which fixed it all was the XML template. I moved the android:id from 'fragment' section to 'RelativeLayout' section.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment_my_section"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:paddingTop="4dp"
    android:background="@drawable/bg"> 

<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
    android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"/>

<fragment
    android:name="com.example.MyFragmentActivity"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
</fragment>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Previously the id was in the 'fragment' section. This was when there was no RelativeLayout and ListView defined in the XML file.

Needless to say I hate XMLs in this Android development world. Majority of the time it has always been an XML file which has wasted my time, without an exception. IDEs don't catch these XML issues well either. I wish Android development get rid or XMLs altogether..